# jQuery function call cannot find the target function

Tags: jquery

Here is the jQuery that WORKS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#calendarId1").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'calendar.png',

            buttonText: 'CAL',
            buttonImageOnly: false,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            closeText: 'Close',
            onClose: removeAria
        });
    dayTripper();
});
   function dayTripper(){
        $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').click(function () {...}
```

The above script does NOT WORK ANY MORE after I tried to move the function dayTripper() to a "public" resource folder, and made a new file "`dayTripper.js`" which contains inside the function `dayTripper()`. I also included the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/default/1_0/scripts/dayTripper.js"` at top of my .xhtml Primefaces page file. Note that the relative path works well with other similar scripts in the same resource folder.

I wonder if it is because jQuery cannot recognize the class "`.ui-datepicker-trigger`" if moved away from the currently running .xhtml page. By principal of scripting, that should not be.

Any explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: The line that I included is at the top of the .xhtml page and was:<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/default/1_0/scripts/dayTripper.js"></script>

Comment: did you include a `<script>` tag for the new file?

Comment: Yes. I did. Actually I have 3 other included's with the same relative paths, and all of them are recognized well. This confirms me that the one related to the dayTripper.js should be ok. Thanks.

Comment: So you're showing us code that works, and asking us why some other code doesn't work?  Can you perhaps demonstrate the problem in the question?  Also, please define what specifically "doesn't work".  When you debug, where/how does it fail?

Comment: I also wonder if it is because the ".ui-datepicker-trigger" class (i.e. auto created by Primefaces datepicker function call - not by myself in my .xhtml page) has not been created yet since Primefaces embeds many calls from its library, and etc...Hence Primefaces is slow, and that class "ui-datepicker-trigger" is not created yet if moved far away from the current .xhtml page.

Comment: the order of includes can matter, import the library stuff before your own?

Comment: David, it doesn't work since the browser cannot display even the calendar; i.e. not even going to dayTripper.js for user to select date.

Comment: I was thinking about what Sweaver said; i.e. order of included lines. Here is my actual included lines: <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/default/1_0/scripts/dayTripper.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/default/1_0/styles/jquery-ui.css"></link>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/default/1_0/styles/calendar.css"></link>.

Comment: Per my experience, compilers of most languages don't care about order. The translation should do everything first before we make any function call. I may be wrong per Sweaver. I will try to move calendar.css on the top to see if it works.

Comment: YES. Sweaver is quite right since after I move the dayTripper.js included line to the end of all included lines. The .xhtml page works as before. Thanks Sweaver.

Comment: Sorry about my previous experiment and said YES. It should be NO since when moving the dayTripper.js to the end, I did not remove the whole dayTripper.js from my current .xhtml page. Now that I remove the whole dayTripper.js from the .xhtml page, it does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

The script tag for dayTripper.js should be at the top and it shouldn't be in an IIFE so that it will be available in the global scope

Comment: I am using Primefaces JSF. When you said "IIFE", can you expand a little more please? Again I put the script tag dayTripper.js line in the current .xhtml page.

Comment: For the working code, the dateTripper() is called right at the same .xhtml page as it is defined in. Also in the working case it is defined outside of the Ready Function (i.e. please see my code in 1st post), does that mean IIFE covered;i.e. globally defined? For the bad code, the whole dayTripper() function just moved away from the .xhtml page to a "public" folder, the global sense should be the same, isn't it? again please tell what code I should have used for the function dayTripper() call when moving it away from the existing .xhtml page.

Comment: An IIFE is immediately invoked function expression in full what it does is make your code modular and it get interpreted imdiatelt the js  interpreter gets to the line where it is declared,that means the variables within it are not exposed to the window object. So my point is since the function in dayTripper.js is needed in the function you took it out of just you should have <script SRC='location-to-dayTripper.js'></script>  before the other script that calls the function declared in dayTripper.js

Comment: I found my problem: It was because the script include tag line for the .js file defining the function dayTripper() was not put at the header section of the parent .xhtml page (i.e. that parent includes the child .xhtml page that calls the function dayTripper(). Note that the code syntax for the calling as well as the defining are exact as in my first post. Thanks for all inputs anyway.

Comment: I am glad you fixed it